# Context: how configure style of fields

Tags: context, textfield

I am learning how to use pdf's field with Context.

Here the code:

```
%\usesymbols [fontawesome]
\setuppagenumbering[location=]  

\setupinteraction   [state=start]
%\setupbodyfont[utopia,10pt]

\setupfield
    [shortString]
    [reset]
    [
        width=45mm,
        option=printable,
        frame=off,
        bottomframe=on,
        height=.6em,
        offset=-1mm,
        frameoffset=2mm,
        background=color,
        backgroundcolor=gray,
        style=normal,
    ]
\definefield
    [Name]
    [line]
    [shortString]
    []
    []

\definefield
    [pop]
    [popup]
    [shortString]
    [{test,test1}]
    []
\starttext

Il sottoscritto \field[Name]\\

Il sottoscritto \field[pop]

\stoptext
```

How Can I setup the same font and style between the text and the input text of the fields?

[image: My test]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

> How Can I setup the same font and style between the text and the input text of the fields?

You can't.

ConTeXt only allows you to use exactly the following fonts in fields:

- Times (Roman, Italic, Bold, Bold Italic)
- Helvetica (Regular, Oblique, Bold, Bold Oblique)
- Courier (Regular, Oblique, Bold, Bold Oblique)
- Zapf Dingbats (Regular)

[(source)](https://github.com/contextgarden/context/blob/101f43df352f7251a04d2018dda25fb664978a79/tex/context/base/mkiv/lpdf-fld.lua#L301-L329)

But ConTeXt doesn't actually include any of these fonts for body text use! You can use Termes, Heros, and Cursor as really close substitutes, but you'll never get anything identical.

You can set the font used with the `style` key as the fifth argument of `\setupfield`:

```tex
\setupinteraction[state=start]

\setupfield
    [test]
    [reset]
    []
    []
    [style={\rmit}]
\definefield
    [Name]
    [line]
    [test]
    []
    [Default]

\starttext
\field[Name]
\stoptext
```

[image: output]

Viewer support for setting the field font is pretty poor—many viewers will ignore the font setting and just display a default font.